# About Semigroup & Semiring homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, semigroups, semiring

This is [Theorem 2.1.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA30) from Scharlau's book *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms*

[image]

Can somebody explain me why $R$ has zero element $[a,a]$ and negative element $[b,a]$? My guess: I think it is due to the equivalence relation we define we want $c=0$ element hence negative of $[a,b]$ is $[b,a]$.

Why it's a homomorphism is clear but why $[a,b]=[a,0]-[b,0]$? Also, why $f'$ is a well defined group homomorphism and why it is uniquely determined is not clear to me. Somebody help regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why R has zero element $[a,a]$

In order to verify that some element "$E$" is the zero you have to check that $a+E=E+a=a$ for all $a$. So let's do it. Let $a, r, q$ be any elements of $R^+$. Then

$$[a,a]+[r,q]=[a+r,a+q]$$

by the definition. Also by the definition of $\sim$ we have $(r,q)\sim(a+r,a+q)$ because you can simply choose $c:=a$. It follows that $[a+r, a+q]=[r,q]$ and thus $[a,a]$ is the neutral element. Note that the element $[a,a]$ does not depend on the choice of $a$, i.e. $[a,a]=[b,b]$ for any $a,b$.

> why R has (...) negative element $[b,a]$

Again, you need to follow the definition of the (additive) inverse: $I$ is the inverse of $a$ if $a+I=I+a=E$ where $E$ is the neutral element. We already know that $[a,a]$ is neutral. Now let $r,q$ be two elements and consider

$$[r,q]+[q,r]=[r+q,r+q]$$

by the definition. Now since $[a,a]$ is the neutral element and it doesn't depend on the choice of $a$, then we simply put $a:=r+q$ to obtain that $[r+q,r+q]$ is the neutral element and so $[q,r]$ is the (additive) inverse of $[r, q]$.

> why $[a,b]=[a,0]-[b,0]$?

What is "$-$"? It is the operation of taking the additive inverse, i.e. $-[r, q]=[q, r]$ as we've proved earlier. With that you have

$$[a,0]-[b,0]=[a,0]+[0,b]=[a,b]$$

Note the subtlety: this only makes sense if $R$ has zero to begin with. But it's not a problem if it doesn't have because you can always add the neural element to any semisubgroup, simply by forcing $a+0=0+a=a$ for any $a$.

> why $f'$is well defined group homomorphism

You have $f'([a,b])=f(a)-f(b)$. In order to prove that it is well defined we have to show that the definition doesn't depend on the choice of $a,b$. So assume that $[a,b]=[a',b']$, i.e. $a+b'+c=a'+b+c$ for some $c$. Then we have

$$f(a)+f(b')+f(c)=f(a+b'+c)=f(a'+b+c)=f(a')+f(b)+f(c)$$

Note that the codomain of $f$ is an abelian **group** hence we can subtract $f(c)$ from both sides to obtain

$$f(a)+f(b')=f(a')+f(b)$$
$$f(a)-f(b)=f(a')-f(b')$$
$$f'([a,b])=f'([a',b'])$$

> why it is uniquely determine

So assume that $g:R\to S$ is another homomorphism such that $g([r,0])=f(r)$ for all $r\in R^+$. We have to show that $g(x)=f'(x)$ for all $x\in R$. Indeed

$$g([r,q])=g([r,0]-[q,0])=g([r,0])-g([q,0])=f(r)-f(q)=f'([r,q])$$

**Side note:** The construction is widely known as the Grothendieck group/ring. You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group

> why it is equivalence relation as I cannot prove symmetry

- **Reflexivity:** Let $r, q$ be two elements of $R^+$. Pick any $c\in R^+$. Then $r+q+c=r+q+c$ meaning $(r,q)\sim (r,q)$.
- **Symmetry:** Let $r,q,r',q'\in R^+$. Assume that $(r,q)\sim (r',q')$. Then there is $c\in R^+$ such that $r+q'+c=r'+q+c$. Switch sides to obtain $r'+q+c=r+q'+c$ meaning $(r',q')\sim (r,q)$.
- **Transitivity:** Let $r,q,r',q', r'', q''\in R^+$. Assume that $(r,q)\sim (r',q')$ and $(r',q')\sim (r'', q'')$. Then we have $c, c'\in R^+$ such that $r+q'+c=r'+q+c$ and $r'+q''+c'=r''+q'+c'$. Then we have
  $$r+q''+(q'+c+c)'=(r+q'+c)+q''+c'=$$
  $$=(r'+q+c)+q''+c'=(r'+q''+c')+q+c=$$
  $$=(r''+q'+c')+q+c=r''+q+(q'+c+c')$$
  meaning $(r,q)\sim (r'', q'')$.

> Examples

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Consider $H\subseteq G$ a semisubgroup, i.e. $a+b\in H$ whenever $a,b\in H$. Assume furthermore that for any $g\in G$ there is $h,k\in H$ such that $g=h-k$. Then the Grothendieck construction for $H$ yields $G$ up to isomorphism. Indeed, if $\overline{H}$ is the Grothendieck extension of $H$ then we define $f:\overline{H}\to G$ by $f([h,k])=h-k$. You can easily check that $f$ is a monomorphism (kernel is trivial). The fact that every element of $G$ can be represented as $h-k$ means that $f$ is an epimorphism. All together $f$ is an isomorphism.

So for some concrete examples: let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the group of integers and let 
$$\mathbb{Z}_{\geq k}=\{k,k+1,k+2,\ldots\}=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\ |\ n\geq k\}$$
You can easily verify that $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq k}$ is a semisubgroup for $k\geq 0$. Furthermore every element $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $m=(k+m)-k$ so $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq k}$ satisfies our other condition. Therefore $\overline{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq k}}\simeq\mathbb{Z}$.

> about that R is uniquely determined upto isomorphisam.

So assume that we have two groups/rings: $R_1, R_2$, both satisfy the universal property. So we have two homomorphisms: $i_1:R^+\to R_1$ and $i_2:R^+\to R_2$. Now since $R_1$ and $R_2$ have the universal property we can "extend" both of them **but** with opposite groups to obtain $e_1:R_2\to R_1$ and $e_2:R_1\to R_2$. By the definition $e_2\circ i_1=i_2$ and $e_1\circ i_2=i_1$. Now consider the composition $e_1\circ e_2$. It follows that

$$e_1\circ e_2\circ i_1=e_1\circ i_2=i_1$$

And since the identity $\text{id}_1:R_1\to R_1$ satisfies the same: $\text{id}_1\circ i_1=i_1$ it follows that $e_1\circ e_2=\text{id}_1$ by the uniquenes of the Grothendieck extension.

Analogously we prove that $e_2\circ e_1=\text{id}_2$ which proves that both $e_1$ and $e_2$ are inverses of each other so $R_1$ is isomorphic to $R_2$.

Comment: can you give me some example of grothendieck construction such as construction of integers from natural and one more something non-trivial explicitly.

Comment: @sscool if $G$ is an abelian group and $H\subseteq G$ is a subsemigroup (note semi) such that every element of $G$ is of the form $h-k$ for some $h,k\in H$ then the Grothendieck construction for $H$ yields $G$ up to isomorphism. For example the set of all naturals greater than fixed $m$ yields $\mathbb{Z}$. Will that be enough?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876267/about-invariant-of-qudratic-space please help me if you know it.

Comment: @freakish can you please explain second part of theorem?

Comment: @Ninjahatori You mean "(semi)ring" case instead of "(semi)group" case? Everything is the same except now you additionally have a mutiplication. You just have to show that at each step the multiplication is preserved as well. On top of that you no longer deal with (semi)group homomorphisms but with (semi)ring homorphisms.

Comment: That unique R group part.

Comment: @freakish about that R is uniquely determined upto isomorphisam.

Comment: @Ninjahatori I've updated the answer.

Comment: @freakish I have asked question regarding Witt group check my activity.

Comment: @freakish https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883001/about-elements-of-witt-group

Comment: @freakish https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884545/witt-ring-of-field I have uploaded question please help me out regarding this