# About invariant of quadratic space

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, invariant-theory

The following excerpt is from Scharlau: *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms*, [pages 35-36](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA35).

[image]

[image]

One associates "in-variants" with the quadratic space so that the space is determined by its invariants as completely as possible. What is meaning of this statement? 
Also I know that dimension is invariant property for vector space and it is equal or greater than 0 so we can construct Grothendieck ring of integers $Z$.  But why hyperbolic space has Grothendieck ring  $Z/2Z$?
How to construct it from hyperbolic space? Also someone explain ideal part which is totally confusing for me?

Answer (score 2):

An invariant is a property that is preserved under certain transformations. In particular if $\mathcal{O}$ is a class of objects (more formally a category), $\mathcal{X}$ is a class of possible values and $P:\mathcal{O}\to\mathcal{X}$ is a property then we say that $P$ is an invariant if $P(X)=P(Y)$ whenever $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$.

> Examples of invariants

- In the class of all groups: $P$ given by $P(G)=|G|$ (i.e. the cardinality of $G$) is an invariant. For short cardinality is an invariant for groups.
- In the class of all topological spaces: $P$ given by $P(X)=\begin{cases}\text{true} &\text{if }X\text{ is compact} \\ \text{false} &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. For short compactness is an invariant for topological spaces
- In the class of all vector spaces over a field $k$: $P$ given by $P(V)=\dim_k(V)$ is an invariant.

The last example is especially important because it is actually a **complete** invariant (the terminology is not standard), meaning the converse is also true: if $\dim_k(V)=\dim_k(W)$ then $V$ is isomorphic to $W$. Note that other two examples are not complete.

**Counterexample:** In the class of all metric spaces the property of $M$ being a complete metric space is not an invariant. Indeed, $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ (both with Euclidean metric) but the first one is a complete metric space while the other one is not.

Invariants are important because generally they are easier to calculate then raw classes of isomorphisms. They are tools used for a classification of objects. The goal is to obtain a list of invariants that fully describe an object just like the dimension fully describes a vector space.

Also note the subtlety: the dimension is an invariant for vector spaces equiped with a symmetric bilinear form (recall the definition of the Witt ring) but it is not a complete invariant here. Even though it is a complete invariant for raw vector spaces.

> But why hyperbolic space has Grothendieck ring  $Z/2Z$?

That's not what it says. That doesn't even make sense. For a Grothendieck ring you need a semiring to begin with. Anyway what it says is that there's a ring homomorphism

$$e:W(K)\to\mathbb{Z}_2$$
$$e([V])=\dim(V)\text{ mod }2$$

Formally I should write
$$e([[V], [W]])=\dim(V)-\dim(W)\text{ mod }2$$
 because there are two equivalence relations: one for the Witt ring and one for the associated Grothendieck ring. I'm writing $[V]=[[V],[0]]$ to simplify things.

This is well defined because if $V\sim W$ then by the definition $W$ can be obtained from $V$ by adding hyperbolic spaces. And the dimension of a hyperbolic space is always even meaning that $V$ and $W$ both have either even or odd dimension (even though they can be different). And thus taking ($\text{mod }2$) yields the same value for both. And it's a ring homomorphism because $\dim$ is a semiring homomorphism.

Comment: can you please explain fundamental ideal concept explicitly for both grothendieck and witt ring and about that canonical decomposition?

Comment: @Ashcatcham what exactly you need to know? Everything seems to be there in the text.

Comment: what is meaning of dim splits 1 goes to <1> please explain that I got all other part for Grothendieck group?

Comment: and why there is no direct sum decomposition for map e?

Comment: @Ashcatcham By $1\to <1>$ he means the ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\hat{W}(K)$ such that $f(1)=1$ where $1$ on the right side is the identity of $\hat{W}(K)$. Yeah, the notation is far from clear. This homomorphism is obviously unique if it exists. When he says that "$\dim$ splits" then it means that $\dim\circ f=\text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$. The existance of such homomorphism is equivalent to the direct sum decomposition. This is also known as the splitting lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma (when you read it then put $r:=\text{dim}$).

Comment: and why e does not split like this?

Comment: @Ashcatcham Sometimes it does, e.g. for $K=\mathbb{C}$ we have $W(\mathbb{C})\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$ and so $e:\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ splits. But in general it does not. For example $W(\mathbb{R})\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ and so $e:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ cannot split since there's only a trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}$. The key here is that there's always a nontrivial ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$, $1\mapsto 1$, so $\mathbb{Z}$ is special.

Comment: @freakish Why W(C) is isometric to Z2 and W(R)=Z how to get this explicitly? I know we can count C as even dimensional space so hyperbolic space hence it is Z2 but I can't get why it is true explicitly?  Also for algebraically closed field it is isomorphic to Z2 please explain this also.

Comment: Create a separate question for that.

Comment: @freakish I have created it already