# Witt ring of field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why $W(C)$ is isometric to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $W(R)=\mathbb{Z}$ how to get this explicitly? I know we can count $\mathbb{C}$ as even dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$ so hyperbolic space hence it is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but I can't get why it is true explicitly? Also for algebraically closed field it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ please explain this also.

Comment: I started typing out an answer, but it's far better to reference an explicit construction: https://kyleormsby.github.io/files/quadratic_TNR.pdf Page 9 provides a diagram which captures the essence of the argument I would have otherwise provided, but there are simply too many details, and I'd gloss over them in order to properly enjoy the setting sun.

Answer (score 1):

Calculations of the Witt ring are way too demanding for simple Math Stackexchange answer. I'll give you hints and resources.

For a field $k$ of $\text{char}(k)\neq 2$ the following are equivalent:

- $k$ does not admit quadratic field extension
- $W(k)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$

You can find the proof in the following paper (Proposition 11):

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a1c5/a6eb6f12a8dfd0f1f01cf57d6b4fa4233beb.pdf

Now since algebraically closed fields have no finite extensions then in particular they don't have quadratic field extensions so their Witt ring is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

For reals $\mathbb{R}$ read the same paper, Proposition 26. I actually encourage you to read the whole paper.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888950/isometry-of-quadratic-space

Comment: paper doesn't included proof for most of theorems.